# Android - startActivityForResult() from a RecyclerViewAdapter inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to take a picture by pressing an item inside a `RecyclerView`. If I do `((MainActivity)context).startActivityForResult`, `onActivityResult` in Activity will be called.. How to call it inside the `Fragment` holding the `Adapter`?

I know I can just pass the fragment inside the adapter. But I'm concerned about the memory usage.

Comment: Go through with this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Even though I Overrided `onActivityResult` both in Act and in Frag, the only one launched is inside the `Activity`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to the fragment in the adapter, you can use:

```
fragment.startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);
```

Then in the fragment, you need the following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I do that, the problem is, I have to call it inside the `RecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. Note that `startActivityForResult` has different parameters.

Comment: I can have reference, I did that too and it worked, yes, but I am concerned about memory usage, would it raise my memory usage to a considerable amount by referencing the `Fragment`? I'm still having memory issues too btw

Comment: If you pass the fragment in the constructor of the adapter, I don't see it causing memory problems.

Comment: Why is that so?? Does the Adapter dies along with the Fragment?

Comment: Yes, since only the fragment has the reference to the adapter.

Comment: Alrighty! A colleague said this is a bad practice though, I'm actually going to convert the `Fragment` into `Activity`, but your answer is right! Congrats! *clap hands